# :Hover to Show an Image on .SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a .svg icon and want to show an image when I hover the icon.
It works on normal icon (red square), but somehow it doesn't work .svg (black circle)!

Please give a hand.
Thanks!

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nq3m0oe/)

HTML

```
<div class="red">
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .svg-circle {
        fill-rule: evenodd;
        fill: 'black';
      }
    </style>
    <circle id="myDefsCircle" class="svg-circle" r="20" cx="100" cy="100"/>
  </defs>

   <use x="10" y="0"   xlink:href="#myDefsCircle" class="red"/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
.red:hover {
  fill:red;
  background: url('https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/phone-46-xxl.png') no-repeat;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background-position: center;
}

.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: SVG's do not have a "background" property.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute.  Perhaps try something with the ::before or ::after pseudo selectors.

Comment: @sn3ll, Thanks for your input!  I have tried :before or :after, but still doesn't work on .svg.  I wonder if there are some workarounds

Comment: What you could do is use the "+" adjacent sibling selector, and add a div with the background image directly after the svg.  Then do something like `svg:hover + div {}` That will technically work.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Comment: This is a very good approach!  Yes, it works if I write `svg:hover + div`.  However, I need to rollover on a specific hot-spot (because I have couple more hot-spots inside svg), then it doesn't work.  Please take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/rop4u6v8/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you can do it with SVG:

In SVG you can't use background images. You need to draw the image using the `<image>` tag where instead of the `src` attribute you have to use the `xlink:href` attribute. Also you can't change the `width` and `height` of svg elements in CSS. If you don't want to use Javascript you can't change them.

This is what I've done: I hard coded the `width` and `height` but I've made the element transparent: `opacity:0` and on hover I'm changing the opacity to 1. I hope this is what you were asking.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
.test{opacity:0}
.red:hover ~use{opacity:1}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
  <defs>
  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" id="myDefsCircle" />  
    
 <symbol id="symb1" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
 <use xlink:href="#myDefsCircle" fill="red" />
 <!--<image xlink:href="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/phone-46-xxl.png" width="30" height="30" x="5" y="5" />-->
 
 <!--<image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#blackcat" width="30" height="30" x="5" y="5" />-->
 
 
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/apple.png" width="30" height="30" x="5" y="5" />
 </symbol>

 </defs>
  
   
  <use xlink:href="#myDefsCircle" x="180" y="180" class="red"  />
  <use xlink:href="#symb1"  class="test" pointer-events="none" width="200" height="200" x="100" y="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: @enxanete, Thank you very much for your help, it is well working!

Comment: Thank you for commenting. And yes, you are right.That image doesn't work. That's why I've changed your image with my images: first an SVG and a PNG and both those images are working in Firefox and Safari.